# Как восстановить незакоммиченный файл после перехода на другую ветку?

Tags: git, rider

У меня есть две ветки. Я переключился с одной на другую с помощью UI Rider'а. После этого файл, который был незакоммичен удалился. Я помню его название, но не помню какой был последний на тот момент коммит (какой-то один из последних 10-15). `git stash list` пустой.

Можно ли как-то восстановить файл?

Comment: Я с Райдером не знаком, но в других JetBrain-овских ИДЕ такие файлы попадают в панели Git на закладку Shelf

Comment: в локальной хистори то  нет нужных правок?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov в Shelf нет нужно файла

Comment: @teran вы имеете в виду `git log`? Если да, то там только история коммитов

Comment: я имею в виду https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/local_history.html

Comment: Если его не в Shelf,  то его уже скорее всего нигде нет